# tar: backup before overwriting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, restore, tar

The `cp` command has a feature not well-known to everybody that it can backup before overwriting the target file. Does `tar` has such feature as well during restoring?

I saw an option of `--backup`, but the man page says that it is for "*backup before removal*". That's kind of weird that it only covers removal, but not update.

Any confirmation (not guessing) please?

**Conclusion:**

From `tar --help`, it says:

```
The version control may be set with --backup or VERSION_CONTROL, values are:

  none, off       never make backups
  t, numbered     make numbered backups
  nil, existing   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  never, simple   always make simple backups
```

Comment: Separate to backing up the file, if you want to avoid overwriting existing files see https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not personally familiar with it, but the tar manual does indicate there is a backup feature 
`--backup=typeofbackup`that you can use to avoid overwriting files when extracting an archive, or when creating an archive. The different types of backups are: t, numbered, nil, existing, never, and simple.

> GNU tar offers options for making backups of files before writing new ver-
> sions.

- source: Tar Manual 1.27 pg 78

> They may apply
> to the archive itself before it is created or rewritten, as well as individual
> extracted members.

- source: Tar Manual 1.27 pg 78

> clashing files are automatically be renamed to be unique, and the
> true name is kept for only the last file of a series of clashing files.

- source: Tar Manual 1.27 pg 78

Comment: Worked for me.  Relevant section in the manual:  https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/tar_4.html#SEC92